# nemo bookmark of nfs mounted directory causes delay at cinnamon login and automount fails

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, cinnamon, nemo

I am longtime user of Linux Mint. I have just installed Mint 21.1 Cinnamon edition on a newly-built desktop PC.

I have set up a systemd mount unit to automount an nfs share at startup:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/net-bungle.mount 
[Unit]
Description=bungle fileserver

[Mount]
What=bungle:/srv/nfs4/pool2
Where=/net/bungle
Type=nfs
Options=_netdev,vers=4
TimeoutSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/net-bungle.automount 
[Unit]
Description=automount /net/bungle

[Automount]
Where=/net/bungle

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The .mount unit is present but not enabled; the .automount unit is enabled.

Everything appears to work well: the directory is mounted automatically the first time I access it, with no errors showing in `journalctl -u net-bungle.[auto]mount`.

The problem occurs when I bookmark a directory inside the nfs mount e.g. `/net/bungle/backup` in nemo. There is a 15-20 second delay after entering the login password before the desktop comes up (without the bookmark the desktop comes up instantly).

The logs indicate that nemo is trying to access the directory repeatedly at login time before the network is ready, and it causes the automount to fail:

`journalctl -u net-bungle.automount`

```
Mar 26 08:18:29 zippy systemd[1]: Set up automount automount /net/bungle.
Mar 26 08:19:02 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.automount: Got automount request for /net/bungle, triggered by 3354 (cinnamon)
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.automount: Got automount request for /net/bungle, triggered by 3354 (cinnamon)
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.automount: Got automount request for /net/bungle, triggered by 3354 (cinnamon)
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.automount: Got automount request for /net/bungle, triggered by 3354 (cinnamon)
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.automount: Got automount request for /net/bungle, triggered by 3354 (cinnamon)
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.automount: Got automount request for /net/bungle, triggered by 3354 (cinnamon)
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.automount: Failed with result 'mount-start-limit-hit'.
```

`journalctl -u net-bungle.mount`:

```
Mar 26 08:19:04 zippy systemd[1]: Mounting bungle fileserver...
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy mount[4394]: mount.nfs: Network is unreachable
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: Failed to mount bungle fileserver.
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: Mounting bungle fileserver...
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy mount[4481]: mount.nfs: Network is unreachable
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: Failed to mount bungle fileserver.
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: Mounting bungle fileserver...
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy mount[4483]: mount.nfs: Network is unreachable
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: Failed to mount bungle fileserver.
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: Mounting bungle fileserver...
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy mount[4485]: mount.nfs: Network is unreachable
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: Failed to mount bungle fileserver.
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: Mounting bungle fileserver...
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy mount[4487]: mount.nfs: Network is unreachable
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: Failed to mount bungle fileserver.
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.mount: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: net-bungle.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 26 08:19:05 zippy systemd[1]: Failed to mount bungle fileserver.
```

Does anyone know of a way to tell nemo not to access bookmarked directories at startup? `nemo --help` doesn't show anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for anyone coming across this in future...

The problem turned out to be NetworkManager not playing nicely with my bridged ethernet setup. I replaced NetworkManager with systemd-networkd and the issue went away.